# Add free gifted product for a minimal cart amount in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, cart

I want to give customers with orders above $50 a free gift. Not if a specific product is in the cart (there are some examples here on stackoverflow and below).

After some research I found the following code to add a free product if another specific product is added to the cart.

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'bbloomer_add_gift_if_id_in_cart' );
 
function bbloomer_add_gift_if_id_in_cart() {
 
   if ( is_admin() ) return;
   if ( WC()->cart->is_empty() ) return;
 
   $product_bought_id = 32;
   $product_gifted_id = 57;
 
   // see if product id in cart
   $product_bought_cart_id = WC()->cart->generate_cart_id( $product_bought_id );
   $product_bought_in_cart = WC()->cart->find_product_in_cart( $product_bought_cart_id );
 
   // see if gift id in cart
   $product_gifted_cart_id = WC()->cart->generate_cart_id( $product_gifted_id );
   $product_gifted_in_cart = WC()->cart->find_product_in_cart( $product_gifted_cart_id );
 
   // if not in cart remove gift, else add gift
   if ( ! $product_bought_in_cart ) {
      if ( $product_gifted_in_cart ) WC()->cart->remove_cart_item( $product_gifted_in_cart );
   } else {
      if ( ! $product_gifted_in_cart ) WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_gifted_id );
   }
}
```

Found here: https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-buy-1-product-add-free-product-cart-programmatically/

I also tried this code but it doesn't update if the cart changes:

```
function aapc_add_product_to_cart() {
    global $woocommerce;
    
    $cart_total = 50;   

    if ( $woocommerce->cart->total >= $cart_total ) {
        if ( ! is_admin() ) {
            $free_product_id = 12989;  // Product Id of the free product which will get added to cart
            $found      = false;

            //check if product already in cart
            if ( sizeof( WC()->cart->get_cart() ) > 0 ) {
                foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
                    $_product = $values['data'];
                    if ( $_product->get_id() == $free_product_id )
                        $found = true;                  
                }
                // if product not found, add it
                if ( ! $found )
                    WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $free_product_id );
            } else {
                // if no products in cart, add it
                WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $free_product_id );
            }        
        }
    }        
}

add_action( 'template_redirect', 'aapc_add_product_to_cart' );
```

Is there any way to change that code to work with any product and limit only to the cart total?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Updated**

With the following, a free gifted product will be added to cart if subtotal is up to a specific amount:

```php
// Add free gifted product for specific cart subtotal
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'check_free_gifted_product' );
function check_free_gifted_product( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    // Settings
    $free_product_id   = 37;
    $targeted_subtotal = 50;

    $cart_subtotal     = 0; // Initializing

    // Loop through cart items (first loop)
    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ){
        // When free product is is cart
        if ( $free_product_id == $cart_item['product_id'] ) {
            $free_key = $cart_item_key;
            $free_qty = $cart_item['quantity'];
            $cart_item['data']->set_price(0); // Optionally set the price to zero
        } else {
            $cart_subtotal += $cart_item['line_total'] + $cart_item['line_tax'];
        }
    }

    // If subtotal match and free product is not already in cart, add it
    if ( ! isset($free_key) && $cart_subtotal >= $targeted_subtotal ) {
        $cart->add_to_cart( $free_product_id );
    }
    // If subtotal doesn't match and free product is already in cart, remove it
    elseif ( isset($free_key) && $cart_subtotal < $targeted_subtotal ) {
        $cart->remove_cart_item( $free_key );
    }
    // Keep free product quantity to 1.
    elseif ( isset($free_qty) && $free_qty > 1 ) {
        $cart->set_quantity( $free_key, 1 );
    }
}

// Display free gifted product price to zero on minicart
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_price', 'change_minicart_free_gifted_item_price', 10, 3 );
function change_minicart_free_gifted_item_price( $price_html, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {
    $free_product_id   = 27;
    
    if( $cart_item['product_id'] == $free_product_id ) {
        return wc_price( 0 );
    }
    return $price_html;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

**On cart page** *(the free gifted product is "Beanie")*:

[image]

**On mini cart:**

[image]

Comment: sure, thank yoh very much! I tried to find something in `$cart_item['data']`. But I couldn't find any total price

Comment: @Cray It works fine now, see the screenshots (tested on last woocommerce version under storefront clean theme).

Comment: Thank you. On my site there is stoll a subtotal but I guess that's a problem with my theme. Thanks again!

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Hi, not working for me in MiniCart. In cart if my order value goes above targeted subtotal then free product is added and showing 0 but if I check in MiniCart that product is showing original price of the product.